# How to bind array in DOM using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on an application where I bind the list of data into DOM using Vue.js. But it is not working I have used v-for, v-list, and v-repeat but don't get it working. Here is my code both for the template and the script.

```
 <div class="weather-info" v-if="weather!=undefined">
    <div v-repeat="item in weather">
    
    <div class="location-box">
     <div class="location">{{item.day}}
     </div>
     <!-- <div class="date">{{ todaysDate() }}</div> -->
    </div>

    <div class="weather-box">
     <div class="temp">{{ Math.round(item.temprature) }}°c</div>
     <div class="weather">{{Math.round(item.windSpeed)}}</div>
     <div class="icon">
       <img src="{{iconUrl}}.png"/>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Here is the code of the Script

```
export default {
 data() {
  return {
   url_base: "https://localhost:7197/api/weather/",
   weather: undefined,
  };
 },
 methods :  {

    async fetchWeather(e) {
if (e.key == "Enter") {
let response = await axios.get(`${this.url_base}forecast?city=${this.query}`);
this.setResults(response.data);
}
},
setResults(res) {
 console.log(res)
 if(res.isSuccessful === true){
    this.weather = res.response;
 }else{
 // error message
 }
},
},
};
```

The JSON i received in **res** is show below.

[image]

Comment: What isnt working ? you should try with ```v-for```

Comment: Its not bind the array result into DOM means not showing anything

Comment: full code please, we need to see your vue state & whats inside weather variable

Comment: what is your ```weather``` default value is it undefined ?
if it is ```[]``` then you should check the length of ```weather``` in ```v-for```

Comment: @AbbasShaikh v-for is not working either

Comment: Is there an error showing up in console when Vue tries to render using v-for?

Comment: Vue has no built-in directives named `v-list` and/or `v-repeat`. Only `v-for` is supported.

Comment: the key was missing with v-for that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use v-for instead of v-repeat, you can replace it as follow:

```
<div v-for="(item, key) in weather" :key="key">
   {{ item }}
   ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine, Just wondering from where you are invoking the `fetchWeather` method. I just created a working demo below. Please have a look and try to find the root cause of the issue.

Just for a demo purpose I am using mock data but you can replace that with an API call.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    weather: undefined
  },
  mounted() {
    this.weather = [
      { day: 'Day 1' },
      { day: 'Day 2' },
      { day: 'Day 3' },
      { day: 'Day 4' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="weather-info" v-if="weather && weather.length">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in weather" :key="index">
      {{ item.day }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```